# How to pass a datatable and model from view to controller via ajax in asp.net core?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, datatable

I have this view: MyView.cshtml

```
@using System.Data
@model UpdateViewModel

@{
   Layout = null;
   DataTable dt = ViewBag.dTable;
 }

<form> 
    @* some input .... *@ 

    <input type="button" value="ُSave" onclick='SaveBtn(@ViewBag.dTable , @Model)' />
</from>

<div id="ShowTable">
    <table id="mytable">
         @* ... some code that create a table from dt(viewbag.dTable) ... *@ 
    </table>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="bodyModal" class="modal-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function SaveBtn(dt , m) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/SaveUpdate/",
            type: "Post",
            data: {
               dTable: dt,
               updateViewModel: m,
            },
        }).done(function (result) {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#bodyModal').html(result);
        });
    }
</script>
```

My controller.cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SaveUpdate(DataTable dTable, UpdateViewModel updateViewModel)
    {
        // do something ...
        return View();
    }
```

In this view, I get a dt (DataTable type) and a model from controller then create a table (tag) using dt. I want, when user clicks on Save button, via ajax, dt and model pass to controller and do something on them, then at the end a modal opens and displays another view on it. My ajax code does not pass dt and model to controller correctly.
Do you know how I pass them to controller?

Comment: HI, DataTable is a c# Type, Javascript does not understand c# objects when data is sent over the network using AJAX it's normally a JSON, convert you JS 'dt' to JSON 
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110976/how-to-get-values-from-json/30111353

Comment: @saj May I ask you explain it more? How can I use this in my code? Which part of my code does need to change?

Comment: there are multiple questions here so your less likely to get a full n proper answer, the first thing I would do is convert the dt to JSON, as we don't know what dTable is it looks like Jquery, so this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34924719/convert-jquery-datatable-data-as-json/44459638 , perhaps think about narrowing down your questions and resposting